# pitfalls of sourcing file in a function scope

Tags: bash

What's the difference between sourcing file in global scope and in a function scope?
That is between:

```
loadlib ()
{
   source "$1.sh"
}

loadlib lib
```

and

```
source lib.sh
```

Is there something to worry about,  except "local" declarations of variables in lib.sh?

Starting point of this question is the comment "# Since we use some associated arrays, this file should be included from outside a function." from yaourt program.
git clone http://projects.archlinux.fr/yaourt.git
vim ./yaourt/src/lib/util.sh.in

**Documentation**
from man bash

```
.  filename [arguments]  
source filename [arguments]
```

Read  and  execute  commands from filename in the current shell environment and return the exit status of the last command executed from filename.  If filename does not contain a slash, file names in PATH are used to find the directory containing filename.  The file searched for  in PATH  need  not  be  executable.  When bash is not in posix mode, the current directory is searched if no file is found in PATH.  If the sourcepath option to the shopt builtin command is turned off, the PATH is not searched.  If any arguments are supplied, they become the positional parameters when filename is executed.  Otherwise the positional parameters are unchanged.  The return status is the status of the last command
exited within the script (0 if no commands are executed), and false if filename is not found or cannot be read.

Comment: One minor difference: //The positional parameters ($1 $2 ...) in the 'plain' version will be the parameters passed to the (original) script. When called via 'loadlibs' the positional parameters will be $1=lib. It will only impact libraries that expected positional parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The bash man page states:

> All other aspects of the shell execution environment are identical between a function and  its  caller
>      with these exceptions: the DEBUG and RETURN traps (see the description of the trap builtin under SHELL
>      BUILTIN COMMANDS below) are not inherited unless the function has been given the trace attribute  (see
>          the  description  of the declare builtin below) or the -o functrace shell option has been enabled with
>          the set builtin (in which case all functions inherit the DEBUG and RETURN traps), and the ERR trap  is
>          not inherited unless the -o errtrace shell option has been enabled.
>
> Variables local to the function may be declared with the local builtin command.  Ordinarily, variables
>          and their values are shared between the function and its caller.

Implying 'local' variables and positional parameters to be the only exceptions.